# Regex pattern for Prometheus exporter

Tags: regex, weblogic, prometheus

I am trying to create a regex pattern for one of the prometheus exporter (jmx exporter) configuration file to export weblogic jms queues.

**My String is as below**

```
(com.bea<ServerRuntime=AC_Server-10-100-40-122, Name=iLoyalJMSModule!AC_JMSServer@AC_Server-10-100-40-122@com.ibsplc.iloyal.eai.EN.retro.outErrorqueue, Type=JMSDestinationRuntime, JMSServerRuntime=AC_JMSServer@AC_Server-10-100-40-122><>MessagesCurrentCount)
```

And the RegEx is as below

**Pattern**

```
com.bea<ServerRuntime=(.+), Name=(.+), Type=(.+), JMSServerRuntime=(.+)<>(MessagesCurrentCount|MessagesPendingCount)
```

**Name to display in Prometheus exporter output**

```
name: "weblogic_jmsserver_$1_$5"
```

**Current Output**

```
weblogic_jmsserver_ac_server_10_100_40_122_messagescurrentcount
```

Now i would like to add the queue `outErrorqueue` name to my output from the `Name=` string and the final output should be like below.

**Required Output**

```
weblogic_jmsserver_ac_server_10_100_40_122_outErrorqueue_messagespendingcount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the number of capture groups from 5 to the 2 that you need in the replacement. Instead of using `.+`, you can either use `.*?` or use a negated character class to match any char except a commen `[^,]+`

If the surrounding parenthesis of the example data should not be part of the replacement, you can use:

```
\(com\.bea<ServerRuntime=([^,]+), Name=[^,]+, Type=[^,]+, JMSServerRuntime=.+?<>(Messages(?:Current|Pending)Count)\)
```

In the replacement use:

```
weblogic_jmsserver_$1_outErrorqueue_$2
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m8CPun/1)